# How to Edit any posted text in react

Tags: html, templates

I can see the title to be edited but the question is how can I view a detailed bar for editing? in the tutorials, I am following works correctly but with me, it doesn't.

```
'{{#each errors }}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{text}}</div>

{{else}}
{{/each}}

<div class="card card-body">
    <h3>Edit Candidates</h3>
    <form action="/ideas" method="post">    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{idea.title}}" required>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="details">Details</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="details"  required {{idea.details}}></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. This question doesn't appear to use `react` at all. Please review [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to provide improved details, including sources you're working from and what specifically isn't working.